# HTML Contact Form failure to send the message

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I created a contact form with HTML but I always get an error when trying to submit the form. I don't know php but I have done quite a research and checked that there are not syntax mistakes.

I have checked that the email address is working properly.

HTML

```
   <form action="mail.php" id="form" method="post" name="form">
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
      <input id="email" name="email" type="text">
      <textarea id="msg" name="message"></textarea>
      <a href="javascript:%20check_empty()" id="submit">Send!</a>                
    </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "info@tanie-przeprowadzki-warszawa.pl";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT VALIDATION FORM

```
function check_empty(){
    if (document.getElementById('name').value == "" || document.getElementById('email').value == "" || document.getElementById('msg').value == "") {
        alert("Fill All Fields!");
    } else {
    document.getElementById('form').submit();
        alert("Form Submitted Successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: For troubleshooting, in your PHP, after the line where you define $message, add this: die($name,$email,$message); and see if it's getting that far.

Comment: @TBowman sorry but I don't understand where I have to add this.

Comment: @JohnConde The error I get is just the "Error!" message in line 9 in my PHP

Comment: @Alvarado87 after this: $message = $_POST['message'];

Comment: @TBowman if I just add: die($name,$email,$message); in the next line I get a syntax error in that line

Comment: If you get a syntax error, then one of those values is empty. Try to filter out the possibility of having empty values inserted into your variables.

Comment: No but is in the same line where I add what you told me, so it should be bad or I'm doing something wrong.